# ExtJS 4.2 - Bind Grid to FieldSet - FieldSet is Not Updating - MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a Grid that populates from a service call (SOAP/XML) from a Store. The Grid populates fine; However, when I select an item in the Grid, I am trying to Bind that value to a FieldSet.

When selecting the item in the Grid, I debug and I see that the Model selected item has been updated properly, but when I do a loadRecord, the FieldSet does not update. I do not get any errors, but the FieldSet is not updating.

Here is my sample code. I am trying to minimize it as much as possible because I am using MVC and my application is starting to get large.

**PhoneCallsModel.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.model.PhoneCallsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'employeeSsn'},
        {name: 'callRsn'},
        {name: 'callDt'},
        {name: 'callType'},
        {name: 'callFor'},
        {name: 'callerName'},
        {name: 'callNoteDesc'}
    ]
});
```

**PhoneCallsStore.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.store.PhoneCallsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'phoneCallsStore',
        model: 'DG.model.PhoneCallsModel',
        autoLoad: false
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'return',
            record: 'contents',
            employeeSsn: '@employeeSsn',
            callRsn: '@callRsn',
            callDt: '@callDt',
            callType: '@callType',
            callFor: '@callFor',
            callerName: '@callerName',
            callNoteDesc: '@callNoteDesc'
        }
    }
});
```

I load the Store dynamically... just an FYI. No issues loading the data or displaying it in the Grid.

I have several ViewPort that I am using to have multiple pages. In my Controller, I am creating a new ViewPort and adding the main Panel that contains the Grid and the FieldSet form.

**SearchCommand.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.controller.SearchCommand', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'searchView button': {
                searchData: this.doSearch }
        });
    },

    doSearch: function (caseID) {
        if (caseID) {
            Ext.create(Ext.container.Viewport, {
                requires: [
                    'DG.view.PhoneCallsDataGrid',
                    'DG.view.PhoneCallNoteView'
                ],

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'phoneCallsView'
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**PhoneCallsView.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.view.PhoneCallsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.phoneCallsView',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 800,
    border: 0,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    layout: 'column',    // Specifies that the items will now be arranged in columns
    frame: true,

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'left',
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },

    items: [
        {
            x: 10,
            y: 177,
            xtype: 'phoneCallsDataGrid',
            itemId: 'getDataGridSelection',
            height: 225,
            width: 1175,
            action: 'getSelectedItem'
        },
        {
            x: 10,
            y: 225,
            xtype: 'phoneCallNoteView',
            height: 200,
            width: 1175
        },
        {
            x: 10,
            y: 480,
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'getDataButton',
            text: 'Refresh',
            action: 'getData'
        }
    ]
});
```

**PhoneCallsDataGrid.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.view.PhoneCallsDataGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.phoneCallsDataGrid',
    store: 'PhoneCallsStore',
    title: 'Phone Call List',
    columnLines: true,
    border: false,
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    loadMask: true,
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Case SSN', dataIndex: 'employeeSsn'},
            {header: 'Call Reason', dataIndex: 'callRsn'},
            {header: 'Call Receive Date', dataIndex: 'callDt'},
            {header: 'Call Type', dataIndex: 'callType'},
            {header: 'Call For', dataIndex: 'callFor'},
            {header: 'Caller Name', dataIndex: 'callerName'},
            {header: 'Callback Number', dataIndex: 'callbackNo'},
            {text: 'Notes', header: 'Notes', dataIndex: 'callNoteDesc', width: 475,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**PhoneCallNoteView.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.view.PhoneCallNoteView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    alias: 'widget.phoneCallNoteView',
    xtype: 'form',

    margin: '0 0 0 10',

    title: 'Phone Call Details',

    defaults: {
        width: 1100
    },

    defaultType: 'textfield',

    items: [
        {
            id: 'callNoteDesc',
            fieldLabel: 'Note',
            name: 'callNoteDesc'
        }
    ]
});
```

Now, I have a Controller (I removed a bunch of stuff not needed for this posting) that on init it has a listener for selectionchange on the phoneCallsDataGrid:

**PhoneCallsCommand.js -**

```
Ext.define('DG.controller.PhoneCallsCommand', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['PhoneCallsStore'],
    models: ['PhoneCallsModel'],
    views: ['PhoneCallsView',
        'PhoneCallsDataGrid',
        'PhoneCallNoteView'],

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'phoneCallNoteView',
            selector: 'form'
        }
    ],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'phoneCallsDataGrid': {
                selectionchange: this.gridSelectionChange,
                viewready: this.onViewReady
            }
        });
    },

    gridSelectionChange: function (model, records) {
        debugger;

        if (records[0]) {
            this.getPhoneCallNoteView().loadRecord(records[0]);
        }
    },

    onViewReady: function (grid) {
        debugger;

        grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }
});
```

On gridSelectionChange I see the model has the correct selected item data, and the records is correct as well. I do not get any errors when doing:

```
this.getPhoneCallNoteView().loadRecord(records[0]);
```

Here is what the data looks like when I debug the method gridSelectionChange. You can see that the records looks good, and also the model looks good (I edited some personal info I did not want displayed on the screenshot):

[image: screenshot of data]

[image: screenshot of model]

However, the callNoteDesc field is not displaying the Notes. Any idea what is going on and how I can Bind properly from the Grid Notes to the FieldSet Note?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.form.FieldSet` does not have a method `loadrecord`, `Ext.form.panel` does.

I'd say you need to make a ref for the form and change this:

```
this.getPhoneCallNoteView().loadRecord(records[0]);
```

to this:

```
this.getPhoneCallsView().loadRecord(records[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I tried what you suggested and I get the following error:   Uncaught TypeError: Object function j(){return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)||null} has no method 'loadRecord'

Comment: I changed the FieldSet to a Panel and used what I pasted below, and it works! Thanks for directing me in the right place.               var r = Ext.widget('phoneCallsView');
            r.loadRecord(records[0]);

Comment: Change your answer and I will mark it as answered. If not, I can add an answer. I am not sure why this.getPhoneCallsView() didn't work. I had to use Ext.widget instead.

Comment: Try adding `autoCreate: true` to the reference

Comment: Actually that didn't work... it jumbles my screen. Like it builds another view on top of the one there. This is after doing  var r = Ext.widget('phoneCallsView'); r.loadRecord(records[0]);. Not sure what is happening. Let me try adding autoCreate:true.

Comment: I added autoCreate: true to the reference and I still get the TypeError listed in my first comment above.

Comment: I got it!!! Ext.widget creates a new instance, which is why my screen was all overlapping and crazy looking. So, I used:  var r = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('phoneCallsView')[0];
            r.loadRecord(records[0]);

Comment: 2 Things: you should give your component an id, you are already treating it as a unique element (with `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('phoneCallsView')[0]`). And refs internally use `Ext.ComponentQuery` to reference the component (only the first element like you did with `[0]`, so you should really be able to use those.